# Display custom message for checkbox (terms of service/privacy)

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I am still new to Symfony and Php, so I am using the CheckboxType code from Symfony docs.

Currently no message is appearing if a user attempts to register and the checkbox is unchecked, but it will still prevent the user from making a account.

(1) I would like a error message to appear next to the checkbox in red stating the box must be checked in order to proceed. I would also like to customize this message.

Thank you!

**Register.html**

```
  {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Register!</h1>

                {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_row(form.username) }}
                {{ form_row(form.email) }}
                {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, {
                    'label': 'Password'
                }) }}
                {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, {
                    'label': 'Repeat Password'
                }) }}
                <a href="https://termsfeed.com/terms-service">Terms of service</a>
                {{ form_widget(form.termsAccepted) }}

                <a href="http://t5Project/web/">cancel</a>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate>
                    Register
                </button>

                <br></br>

                <p><a href="https://termsfeed.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>


                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**RegistrationForm.php**

```
  class UserRegistrationForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, ['type' => PasswordType::class])
            ->add('termsAccepted', CheckboxType::class, array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => new IsTrue(),));


    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'Registration']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using:

```
{{ form_widget(form.termsAccepted) }}
```

for rendering the checkbox. This will only render the widget, whereas:

```
{{ form_row(form.termsAccepted) }}
```

as is used by all the user fields would contain the label, the widget and the error message. If you want to keep the widget, e.g. because using `form_row` messes up the template somehow you could render the errors individually using:

```
{{ form_errors(form.termsAccepted) }}
```

You might also want to check out the documentation on [Form Customization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html).